# append query string to any form of URL

Tags: php

I ask user to input a URL in a text-box and need to append a query string to it.

Possible values of URLs can be like:

1. http://www.example.com
2. http://www.example.com/a/
3. http://www.example.com/a/?q1=one
4. http://www.example.com/a.html
5. http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=one

Now I need to add query string to it like "q2=two", so that output would be like:

1. http://www.example.com/?q2=two
2. http://www.example.com/a/?q2=two
3. http://www.example.com/a/?q1=one&q2=two
4. http://www.example.com/a.html?q2=two
5. http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=one&q2=two

How can I achieve the following using PHP?

Comment: Simply use: `echo http_build_url($url, array("query" => "the=query&parts=here"), HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY);`. But you'll need `pecl install pecl_http` or install [jakeasmith/http_build_url](https://github.com/jakeasmith/http_build_url) via composer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
<?php

$urls = array(
         'http://www.example.com',
         'http://www.example.com/a/',
         'http://www.example.com/a/?q1=one',
         'http://www.example.com/a.html',
         'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=one'
        );

$query = 'q2=two';

foreach($urls as &$url) {
   $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
   if ($parsedUrl['path'] == null) {
      $url .= '/';
   }
   $separator = ($parsedUrl['query'] == NULL) ? '?' : '&';
   $url .= $separator . $query;
}

var_dump($urls);
```

#### Output

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "http://www.example.com/?q2=two"
  [1]=>
  string(32) "http://www.example.com/a/?q2=two"
  [2]=>
  string(39) "http://www.example.com/a/?q1=one&q2=two"
  [3]=>
  string(36) "http://www.example.com/a.html?q2=two"
  [4]=>
  &string(43) "http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=one&q2=two"
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/KHSlbmgr).

Comment: Unfortunately this example doesn't work when the url contains a hash after the query string.

Comment: @Tom You could easily modify it to do so. Remove the `PHP_URL_FRAGMENT` from each one and append it back after the transformation.

Comment: Downvoted. Key [0] in provided example output is not a valid URL. Should have a trailing slash after `.com`. Correct URL needs to be: `http://www.example.com/?q2=two` not `http://www.example.com?q2=two`

Comment: @Mattias Browsers appear to *correct* it, but I can update the answer.

Comment: You should probably use `(!array_key_exists('query',$ParsedURL) || is_null($ParsedURL['query']))` instead of `($parsedUrl['query'] == NULL)` to avoid `undefined index` errors.

Comment: !isset on $parsedUrl['query'] would be better avoid undefined

Comment: Simply use: `echo http_build_url($url, array("query" => "the=query&parts=here"), HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY);`. But you'll need `pecl install pecl_http` or install [jakeasmith/http_build_url](https://github.com/jakeasmith/http_build_url) via composer.

Answer (score 16):

$url is your URL. Use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function

```
if(strpos($url,'?') !== false) {
   $url .= '&q2=two';
} else {
   $url .= '?q2=two';
}
```

Comment: That should be `strpos($url,'?') !== false`

Comment: Use `!== false` when you use strpos. `> -1` is JavaScript's indexOf's.

Comment: The only time I can see this not working is if the URL has a hash fragment.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but I improved [alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5215908/857025) to account for the "#" part of the string.

```
$urls = array(
    'http://www.example.com',
    'http://www.example.com/a/#something',
    'http://www.example.com/a/?q1=one#soe',
    'http://www.example.com/a.html',
    'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=one'
    );

$query = 'q2=two';

foreach($urls as &$url) {
    $pound = "";
    $poundPos = -1;

    //Is there a #?
    if ( ( $poundPos = strpos( $url, "#" ) ) !== false )
    {
        $pound = substr( $url, $poundPos );
        $url = substr( $url, 0, $poundPos );
    }

    $separator = (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY) == NULL) ? '?' : '&';
    $url .= $separator . $query . $pound;
}

var_dump($urls);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the function I use:

```
/**
 * @param string $url
 * @param $query string|array
 * @return string
 */
public function appendQueryStringToURL(string $url, $query): string
{
    // the query is empty, return the original url straightaway
    if (empty($query)) {
        return $url;
    }

    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    if (empty($parsedUrl['path'])) {
        $url .= '/';
    }

    // if the query is array convert it to string
    $queryString = is_array($query) ? http_build_query($query) : $query;

    // check if there is already any query string in the URL
    if (empty($parsedUrl['query'])) {
        // remove duplications
        parse_str($queryString, $queryStringArray);
        $url .= '?' . http_build_query($queryStringArray);
    } else {
        $queryString = $parsedUrl['query'] . '&' . $queryString;

        // remove duplications
        parse_str($queryString, $queryStringArray);

        // place the updated query in the original query position
        $url = substr_replace($url, http_build_query($queryStringArray), strpos($url, $parsedUrl['query']), strlen($parsedUrl['query']));
    }

    return $url;
}
```

It accepts `query` as `string` or `array`. Also it handles `#` in URL and removes the duplicated query strings automatically. Here is the test as well. Please replace `CLASS_THAT_CONTAINS_appendQueryStringToURL` with the correct `class` in your project:

```
public function testAppendQueryStringToURL()
{
    $helper = new CLASS_THAT_CONTAINS_appendQueryStringToURL();

    $inputsOutputs = [
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com',
            'q' => 'q1=1',
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/?q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com',
            'q' => 'q1=1&q2=2',
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/?q1=1&q2=2'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a/',
            'q' => 'q1=1',
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a/?q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html',
            'q' => 'q1=1',
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a/?q2=2',
            'q' => 'q1=1',
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a/?q2=2&q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q2=two',
            'q' => 'q1=1',
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q2=two&q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=1&q2=2',
            'q' => 'q1=1',
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=1&q2=2'
        ],
        // overwrite the existing
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=1&q2=2',
            'q' => 'q1=3',
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=3&q2=2'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a/#something',
            'q' => 'q1=1',
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a/#something?q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a/?q2=2#soe',
            'q' => 'q1=1',
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a/?q2=2&q1=1#soe'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com',
            'q' => ['q1' => 1],
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/?q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com',
            'q' => ['q1' => 1, 'q2' => 2],
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/?q1=1&q2=2'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a/',
            'q' => ['q1' => 1],
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a/?q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html',
            'q' => ['q1' => 1],
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a/?q2=2',
            'q' => ['q1' => 1],
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a/?q2=2&q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q2=two',
            'q' => ['q1' => 1],
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q2=two&q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=1&q2=2',
            'q' => ['q1' => 1],
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=1&q2=2'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=1&q2=2',
            'q' => ['q1' => 3],
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a.html?q1=3&q2=2'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a/#something',
            'q' => ['q1' => 1],
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a/#something?q1=1'
        ],
        [
            'i' => 'http://www.example.com/a/?q2=2#soe',
            'q' => ['q1' => 1],
            'o' => 'http://www.example.com/a/?q2=2&q1=1#soe'
        ],
    ];

    foreach ($inputsOutputs as $inputOutput) {
        $this->assertEquals($inputOutput['o'], $helper->appendQueryStringToURL($inputOutput['i'], $inputOutput['q']));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect answer! With original URL `/a/?q1=one&q2=twoo` by append query `q2=two` it becomes `/a/?q1=one&q2=two` NOT `/a/?q1=one&q2=twoo&q2=two` which is correct.

Answer (score 3):

On a side note, if anyone (like me) implementing this in ***WordPress***, a function already exists: `add_query_arg()`

```
add_query_arg( 'key', 'value', 'http://example.com' );
```

See codex for more examples - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/

Answer (score 1):

If you can install pecl_http then this is a really elegant solution. It can allow you to check if you are overriding a get variable they may have set.

```
$urlComps = parse_url($url);

// Get the current query string
$queryString = isset($urlComps['query']) ? $urlComps['query'] : '';

// Turn it into an array for easy manipulation
parse_str($queryString, $queryVars);

// Make changes to the query vars
$queryVars['q2'] = 'two';

// Empty paths return relative URLs.
$urlComps['path'] = isset($urlComps['path']) ? $urlComps['path'] : '/';

// Make the pecl_http call
$newURL = http_build_url($urlComps, array('query' => http_build_query($queryVars)));
```

Note: if you can't install pecl_http, the only function that comes from that is the last one with the function `http_build_url`. You can fairly easily build your own function to rebuild the URL from its components...

- [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
- [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)
- [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)
- [http_build_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php) * uses pecl_http

Comment: Keep in mind you need to check for magic quotes and transform the GET param too (de-magic-quote-ify) if they're enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Enhancing @alex's answer to account for infinite append of query string

```
/* Append QueryString to current URL */
function querystring_append($query) {
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    if ($parsedUrl['path'] == null) {
        $url .= '/';
    }
    $separator = ($parsedUrl['query'] == NULL) ? '?' : '&';
    if(!substr_count($url,$query)) $url .= $separator . $query;
    return $url;
}
```

Usage:

```
<?=querystring_append("action=logout") ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more tricky that it should be. @alex answer is fine, but it does not support URL fragments nor does it handle duplicate values. I've provided a package for just this scenario. See https://github.com/Nyholm/append_query_string

```
$url = 'https://nyholm.tech?example=yes';
$queryString = http_build_query(['foo'=>'bar']);

$result = append_query_string($url, $queryString);

echo $result;
// https://nyholm.tech?example=yes&foo=bar
```

You may also define how duplicate should be handled. You can decide to:

- Ignore duplicate values
- Replace
- Skip

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP arrays in your query string, and encoding the square brackets causes you some issues in `http_build_query`, here is an alternative (it also combines existing parameters in the supplied URL).

Example:

```
$url = 'https://mywebsite/test?tags[]=beta';
$params = ['tags' => ['a', 'b'], 'arg' => 'val', 'links' => [ 'a' => ['x' =>'three', 'y' => 'four'], 'b'=>2] ];
echo append_querystring_array($url, $params);
// output: 
// https://mywebsite/test?tags[0]=beta&tags[1]=a&tags[2]=b&arg=val&links[a][x]=three&links[a][y]=four&links[b]=2
```

You can use the following under MIT License, copyright 2023 Frank Forte

```
/**
 * Append parameters to a URL query string with support for PHP arrays.
 * Does not encode square brackets.
 * Used under MIT License, copyright 2023 Frank Forte
 * @param string $url  The URL to which we want to append a query string.
 * @param array $params  The parameters to be appended to the query string.
 */
function append_querystring_array($url, $params): string
{
    if (empty($params)) {
        return $url;
    }
    $urlBits = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($urlBits['query'], $urlParams);

    if (!empty($urlBits['scheme'])) {
        $urlBits['scheme'] .= '://';
    }
    if (!empty($urlBits['fragment'])) {
        $urlBits['fragment'] = '#' . $urlBits['fragment'];
    }

    $newUrl = ($urlBits['scheme'] ?? '') . ($urlBits['host'] ?? '') . ($urlBits['path'] ?? '/');

    $params = array_merge_recursive($urlParams, $params);

    $started = false;
    foreach ($params as $p => $val) {
        if ($started) {
            $newUrl .= '&' . urlencode($p) . quarystring_value($val, $p);
        } else {
            $newUrl .=  '?' . urlencode($p) . quarystring_value($val, $p);
            $started = true;
        }
    }
    return $newUrl . ($urlBits['fragment'] ?? '');
}
/**
 * Combine nested array parameters into a PHP query string
 * Used under MIT License, copyright 2023 Frank Forte
 * @param string|value $value  The value to be appended to a query string.
 * @param string $name  The parameter name or array key to which the value will be assigned.
 */
function quarystring_value($value, $name): string
{
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $flatVal = '';
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            if (!empty($flatVal)) {
                $flatVal .= "&$name";
            }
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $flatVal .= '[' . urlencode($k) . ']' . quarystring_value($v, $name . '[' . urlencode($k) . ']');
            } else {
                $flatVal .= '[' . urlencode($k) . ']=' . urlencode($v);
            }
        }
        return $flatVal;
    }
    return '=' . urlencode($value);
}
```