# PHP pages URL setup

Tags: php, html, url

I'm trying to add two languages to my site, but I'm not sure, how to set up the URL for the language switch.

`en.php` and `es.php` contains separate languages:

```
$lang = array(
   "home" => "Home",
   "aboutus" => "About Us",      
);
```

`header.php` contains `include('lang-switch.php');`, which successfully switches languages `<h3><?php printTranslatedString('aboutus') ?></h3>`

if I go to some page like `localhost/user/site/doc1.php?title=blog` by clicking the language switch link from `site/includes/navbar.php` with `<a class="nav-link" href="&lang=en">En</a>` and `&lang=es`.

The URL changes to `localhost/user/site/&lang=en`, or `localhost/user/site/&lang=en`  *Object not found*.

I have to set up the URL with an update of `doc1.php?` document and `title=` name with `&lang=` name like: `localhost/user/site/doc1.php?title=blog&lang=es`

Comment: You need to [append query string to current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215684/append-query-string-to-any-form-of-url). Do not rewrite URL with just `href="?xx"`.

Comment: WordPress specifically has https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/ for such purposes (to add query parameters to any given  URL, or the current one.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep `?title=blog` in url and add `&lang=en/es` after

You have a GET for the name page (blog) AND your lang :)

example : `localhost/user/site/category.php?title=blog&lang=en`

Comment: Hello, sorry I've deleted the post by editing mistake. I've edited the post, please check it

Comment: Is it ok or you're still blocked? I'm not sure ahah

Comment: no, not blocked